# Install the DoctrineMongoDBBundle with Composer

Tags: symfony

I have been trying to install DoctrineMongoDBBundle with Symfony2. I followed this reference http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html

Unfortunately I am getting the following error and could not find a solution.
I have already added the php extension for MongoDB. Could you please give an idea about this ?

- doctrine/mongodb 1.0.3 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.5-dev -> the request
  ed PHP extension mongo has the wrong version (1.2.11) installed.

  - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the request
    ed PHP extension mongo has the wrong version (1.2.11) installed.
  - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the request
    ed PHP extension mongo has the wrong version (1.2.11) installed.
  - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the request
    ed PHP extension mongo has the wrong version (1.2.11) installed.
  - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA5 requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0-BETA1 ->
    no matching package found.

Comment: please see my answer. if you need further guidance how to update your extension please provide your OS and php version. ... but google will definitely tell you how to update your php mongodb extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **update** your PHP MongoDB extension as it is currently version `1.2.11` and you need a version greater than or equal to `1.2.12`.

`ext-mongo` in the error message refers to your PHP extension.

That's exactly what the error message says ... `doctrine/mongodb` needs a greater version of the mongoDB extension and therefore composer can't find a compatible package.

Comment: Thanks Nifr. After upgrading to a greater version I was able to resolve the issue :)

Comment: I found another problem in Ubuntu 12.04. That is also similar to the above issue. I installed the extension but still getting the following issue.

Comment: - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
 - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA5 requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0-BETA1 -> no matching package found.

Comment: check the extension is enabled in php.ini - error message says it's missing from your system so it isn't enabled if you say you installed it.

Comment: Yes I installed and phpinfo shows as enabled .btw version is Version 1.3.0. I am not sure I have missed something.

Comment: having kinda the same issue, thoughts: doctrine/mongodb 1.0.9 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.6-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo has the wrong version (1.6.0-dev) installed.